# multiple elastic network interfaces to increase bandwidth

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

In AWS environment, Adding multiple elastic network interfaces to the EC2 instance can increase the network bandwidth, is it true?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No this is not, the underlying hardware will not increase when you add a virtual NIC  :) to increase bandwith you have to select bigger instance types

Comment: My tests on some c4 instance show the same, however - the following article mentions increased throughput when more interfaces are added : http://www.aerospike.com/blog/boosting-amazon-ec2-network-for-high-throughput/

Comment: Well this is Aerospike words against AWS ones (AWS doesn't commit for precise metrics about network capabilities). So I would say that if you want to hack something dirty to try to spare a few TPS (and maybe get a surprise if AWS changes anything on hypervisor for example), then give this a try. But if you are looking for an AWS backed/best practices compliant way to increase throughput then you should go for a bigger instance. Also network throughput can vary depending on AWS side factors (hypervisor activity, VM location, etc.) or configuration (# of SG rules, VPC flowlogs, routing...) etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's one of the questions asked in AWS Solution Architect exams and the answer is most definitively "No".

However, there are other factors that can impact network bandwidth. Placement groups and Jambo frames can be an option for cases when you run an ensemble of instances that need an enhanced communication between themselves.

If you want an improved bandwidth overall, check [ENA](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking-ena.html)(Enhanced Network Adapter). It can provide up to 25 Gbps for certain connection [types](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/the-floodgates-are-open-increased-network-bandwidth-for-ec2-instances/).

Answer (score 0):

To increase available bandwidth and PPS within EC2, first create a [Placement Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/placement-groups.html) then launch EC2 instance types that support 10Gbps interfaces and SR-IOV (aka. [Enhanced Networking](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/enhanced-networking.html#enhanced_networking_instance_types)).

Comment: placement group is not for bandwith but for very low latency between instances. Moreover, it comes with some cons (hard to add new instances in a later step, limited capacity, single AZ)

Comment: @Tom - Placement Groups affect inter-instance EC2 network performance  (among other factors) by providing a non-blocking 10 Gigabit Ethernet network in the same AZ. Here is a tutorial you might find useful: [link](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/network-throughput-benchmark-linux-ec2/)

Comment: i don't need tuto but thanks. you say it yourself, you have to put EC2 instance types that support 10Gbps interfaces ==> bigger instance types. Try to put a smaller instance and you would not get this bandwith. Placement group is behind the scene the fact that AWS spawns instances as "grouped" as possible (both from a network and physical state). This is really intended for particular cases where cross instance networking matters (e.g oracle RAC), but is an anti cloud pattern as you loose scalability and high availability